# Numbering filtered rows

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I tried to write a Macro, that does the following:

I have a table with many rows and columns, including one column that holds names
like "J63 System" or "J28 System" specifing which part of a machine every part in  a row belongs to. Now I filter for one system and look at the parts: I have one empty column and want to number all the parts with the same part-number, everytime beginning from 1 whenever a new partnumber appears.

but the macro doesnt work correctly and I cant figure out why:

```
Option Explicit

Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, k As Integer
Dim system As String
Dim part0 As String, part1 As String

Sub temato()


n = 887
k = 888

Do

part0 = Cells(n, 2)
part1 = Cells(k, 2)


If Cells(k, 36) = "J64 Tail Rotor" Then
    If part1 = part0 Then
        Cells(k, 3) = Cells(k - 1, 3).Value + 1
        n = n + 1
        k = k + 1
        Else
        Cells(k, 3) = 1
        n = n + 1
        k = k + 1
    End If
Else
    k = k + 1
    Debug.Print n
    Debug.Print k
    Do
        'n bleibt
        part1 = Cells(k, 2)
        If Cells(k, 36) = "J64 Tail Rotor" Then
            If part1 = part0 Then
                Cells(k, 3) = Cells(n, 3).Value + 1
                n = k
                k = k + 1
            Else
                Cells(k, 3) = 1
                n = k
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Else
            k = k + 1
        End If

    Loop While Cells(k, 36) <> "J64 Tail Rotor"

End If

Loop While k <= 1260

End Sub
```

`

Comment: forgot to mention: n and k are the indices for the rows to be checked, n is the first (upper), k the lower index right below n, both running down the table

Comment: You can edit your question and add it there

Comment: Please post a table image so I can refine my answer. Basically you want to select some data from your table based on string matches, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library then copy this macro:

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, sSheet as String
Dim sWorkbookName  as String

sWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""" & 
sWorkbookName & """;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX = 1"""

sSheet="myDataSheet1"
oConn.Open connString
'just an example of SQL, you have to customize it
sSQL = "SELECT [FIELD1], [FIELD2] FROM [" & sSheet & "$] " &  
" WHERE [FIELD1] Like ""*yourmatch"" ORDER BY [FIELD1] ASC"

rs.Open sSQL, oConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

'dump results on a temporary sheet or on the data sheet in an empty column
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("tmp_sheet").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
oConn.Close 
Set rs = Nothing
Set oConn =  Nothing
```

Once you post the table structure and specify the desired result I shall write  the SQL query